# Review stats sidebar sinks below stats

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On the various "stats" pages under /review, the sidebar (linking to the actual review section and offering badge stats) doesn't float nicely to the right, instead sinking below the main content:

[image]
<sup>(Zoomed out for screenshotting ease - happens at 100% zoom as well)</sup>

Comment: Great arrow and dashed line. Was that manually done? Question mark is brilliantly designed as well. Can anybody tell me how to achieve that effect in Photoshop? Using a filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed. It will be live after our next production build.